# How do I use classmethods on defs that work without classmethods but don't work when added

Tags: python, class-method, dice

There is this code that I would like to add classmethods to but don't know how to get it to work.
The code runs fine as is but needs classmethods as stated by the comments

```
# class definition for an n-sided die

# import packages

import random

class MSdie(object): 
  #constructor here

    def __init__( self ):
        self.sides = 6
        self.roll()

#define classmethod 'roll' to roll the MSdie

    def roll( self ):

        self.value = 1 + random.randrange(self.sides)

        return self.value

#define classmethod 'getValue' to return the current value of the MSdie

    def getValue(  self ):

        return self.value

#define classmethod 'setValue' to set the die to a particular value
    #def setValue(self):

def roller():
    r1 = MSdie()

    for n in range (4):
        print(r1.roll())

roller()
```

Comment: I'd recommend you get out of this python course ASAP. Making those methods classmethods is not just nonsensical, it's downright counterproductive. And it's unpythonic to write getters and setters like `getValue` and `setValue` in python. You're being taught to write awful code.

Comment: Is there a chance that "classmethod" is really supposed to mean "method"? Turning these methods into classmethods is so nonsensical that I have a hard time believing that that's really what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment that these methods SHOULD NOT be made classmethods.

But if you must, you cannot use `self` there. Self refers to an object, but classmethods are not called on an object, they're called for a class. So you can no longer store the `value` in the object, because you have none.